# Python filter a list, remove \'n' and empty string

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, filter

I have a list, I try to remove empty string and '\n'

```
re = ['\n', '\n', '0 / 6\n', '1 / 6\n', '2 / 6\n', '3 / 6\n', '4 / 6\n', '5 / 6\n', '6 / 6\n', '\n', 'mobile\n']

resul = map(str.rstrip, re)
print(list(resul))

str_list = filter(None, list(resul))
print(list(str_list))
```

output :

```
['', '', '0 / 6', '1 / 6', '2 / 6', '3 / 6', '4 / 6', '5 / 6', '6 / 6', '', 'mobile']
[]
```

So, the first output is correct, I succed to remove `\n`, but after when I want to remove empty strinf, the list is  emplty.

Comment: How about `res = list(filter(None, [x.strip('\n') for x in re]))`?

Comment: or `re = [x.replace("\n", "") for x in re if x.replace("\n", "") != ""]`

Comment: @OmG Becuase you are using Python 2 where `map` and `filter` return lists. OP is using Python 3 where `map` and `filter` return a generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an empty list just because you are converting `resul` to a list before calling [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) (in order to print it) which consumes it (because [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns a `map` object which is a generator in Python 3). You are actually passing an empty generator to `filter`.

If you remove the premature conversion to list you will get the expected output:

```
 re = ['\n', '\n', '0 / 6\n', '1 / 6\n', '2 / 6\n', '3 / 6\n', '4 / 6\n', '5 / 6\n', '6 / 6\n', '\n', 'mobile\n']

resul = map(str.rstrip, re)
str_list = filter(None, list(resul))
print(list(str_list))

# ['0 / 6', '1 / 6', '2 / 6', '3 / 6', '4 / 6', '5 / 6', '6 / 6', 'mobile']
```

Comment: prefect, it works, but I don't understant why, it return me a empty list after a conversion in list

Comment: @locklockM Because you try to convert the same generator to a list twice. The first time consumes the generator. The second time converts the empty generator to an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Take all non-`\n` values from list and remove `\n` through a list-comprehension:

```
re = ['\n', '\n', '0 / 6\n', '1 / 6\n', '2 / 6\n', '3 / 6\n', '4 / 6\n', '5 / 6\n', '6 / 6\n', '\n', 'mobile\n']

print([x.replace('\n', '') for x in re if x != '\n'])
# ['0 / 6', '1 / 6', '2 / 6', '3 / 6', '4 / 6', '5 / 6', '6 / 6', 'mobile']
```